# cursor positioning with RMB only in a specific file

Tags: 3d-cursor

I'm using 2.8 blender. Suddenly the cursor moves with my LMB and with shift + RMB. I can't figure out why. if I open a new file it's working well (shift+RMB)
thanks for your help.

Comment: I doubt many people are still using 2.8 here. However the keymap setting to set the cursor position is under Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View (Global) > Set 3D Cursor so it might be worth checking that.

Comment: I checked it. It is not a problem of preference as it is happening only in one file.

Comment: If that file is small enough (under 30Meg) and not confidential you could share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there and see if anyone here can offer an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

In the problem file, you most likely had the cursor tool selected when you saved the file:

[image]

That would be why you only have the problem in that particular file. And, why the cursor is moved in the ways you describe.

Just select a different tool, save the file and you should no longer have the problem.

Comment: Thank you Curious, probably was that. I erased this file. because I had a copy of it before.

Comment: That turned out good then. I've always got lots of copies of what I'm working on.